# Google maps Android API V2 instantiate the fragment class

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have the following definition in XML file. I have also created a fragment class which has a method for inflating it. Can you please advise me how to show the map on the class that extends Activity.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
     <fragment
          android:id="@+id/mapview"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) article, here is a piece of code to do what you want:

```
package com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
  static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
  private GoogleMap map;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();
    Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
        .title("Hamburg"));
    Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(KIEL)
        .title("Kiel")
        .snippet("Kiel is cool")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

    // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your activity  extend FragmentActivity and try the following.

```
protected SupportMapFragment map;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapview)).getMap();
        //...........


}
```